# Is there a command to display a Calendar in the terminal?

Tags: command-line, calendar

When working in the terminal it's inconvenient navigating up to the systray to display the current calendar. Is there a command that will display a calendar from the terminal?

Comment: `apropos` and `man` are your friends. When in doubt run `apropos calendar` and see

Comment: Huh, never knew about `apropos` until now, +1

Answer (score 66, accepted):

## `cal` calendar command for terminal

You can use the `cal` command to display a calendar in Julian or Gregorian format. The format depends on your locale settings but can be toggled with parameters.

As the screen below shows the default calendar is the current month. You can use the parameter `-A 2` to display the next two months or `2018` to display all months in that year:

[image: cal]

---

### Ubuntu versions after 20.04

After version **20.04** you may have to use

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ncal
```

Note the `ncal` package does include the `cal` command. Also note that `ncal` is available out of the box in earlier Ubuntu versions before `20.04` as well.

For example on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS ECM:

```
$ ncal

    March 2022        
Su     6 13 20 27   
Mo     7 14 21 28   
Tu  1  8 15 22 29   
We  2  9 16 23 30   
Th  3 10 17 24 31   
Fr  4 11 18 25      
Sa  5 12 19 26
```

Comment: You can also display a specific month with, e.g. `cal 6 2017`.

Comment: Beware that `cal` is somewhat simple-minded about interpreting its arguments. `cal 6 17` will display the calendar for June ***of the year 17*** (i.e., 2000 years ago), and `cal 6` will display the calendar for the year 6.

Comment: @G-Man `cal` is super-sophisticated. For example when in Canada, America or UK type `cal 9 1752` and you will see **September 1752** is missing the ten days Pope Gregory XIII annulled for the Western Catholic world in **October 1582**. People in Italy and possibly Germany and Sweden using `cal 10 1582` will see that calendar is missing the ten days. `cal` works up to the year 9,999 and I've tested February 2100 isn't a leap month and February 2400 is a leap month so it seems as future proof as it is historically accurate.

Comment: Looks like `-A` is depreciated? In `cal` from `util-linux 2.32` that option isn't listed in the manual. You can instead use `cal -3` to display three months (one before, current, one after).

Comment: @MikePierce I tested in Ubuntu 18.04. `cal -3` does display one month before, current and one month after. However you can still use `cal -A3 -B2` to display 2 months before, current month and 3 months after.

Comment: Not apparently included as part of a default Ubuntu install (21.10 for example). What package is it in?

Comment: @Pointy `sudo apt install ncal` should solve that according to [these instructions](https://www.linuxfordevices.com/tutorials/linux/cal-command)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix yea literally 5 minutes ago I stumbled on that, thank you very much!

Answer (score 14):

An alternative is ncal - this displays the calendar in a vertical format, i.e.:

```
    March 2017
Su     5 12 19 26
Mo     6 13 20 27
Tu     7 14 21 28
We  1  8 15 22 29
Th  2  9 16 23 30
Fr  3 10 17 24 31
Sa  4 11 18 25
```

This is slightly harder to read, but supposedly has the advantage that the full year's calendar, by putting four months in each row, fits in a standard sized terminal. In fact, it does not, you have to remove blank lines from the output for it to fit in 24 lines: `ncal 2017 | grep -v '^$'`. The original version of ncal did not have these blank lines. In any case, it takes less vertical space than the traditional calendar output - 26×76, vs 35×66 for `cal`.

Answer (score 11):

[Khal](https://github.com/pimutils/khal) is a calendar application that's much more along the lines of what someone might expect in the year 2020:

[image: khal.png]

It can be installed via `pip3 install khal` (or just pip instead of pip3).  It supports a standard CalDav format and can by synced to a CalDav server.  Additionally it includes an interactive tool (`ikhal` or `khal interactive`) (sort of like `tig` for git) for viewing and editing events in an easier way without having to remember all the flags and syntax and everything.

Comment: I hope you don't mind I took the liberty of adding an image so people can see what they will be getting.

Comment: Thanks, good addition!

Answer (score 6):

## Programmable Calendars

Although these are GUI calendars you can still call them from the terminal. They allow you to navigate through the months and years. They are designed to be called from your Bash scripts but like all Bash commands you can call them from the terminal too.

### `YAD` (Yet Another Dialog) super-charged fork of `Zenity`

[image: calendar yad]

### `Zenity` GUI fork of text-based `dialog`

[image: calendar zenity]

Do not be concerned by the Gtk warning message. You see that a lot when running GUI programs from the terminal. eg. `gedit` and `nautilus` display similar warnings.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative to the standard `cal` is an `enhanced cal` by Alex Matulich. It offers user-configurable colors and the ability to display reminders and appointments next to the calendar.

[Enhanced cal page on Unicorn Research site](http://unicorn.us.com/cal.html)

Edit 2022-06-01: It's available in the repos with `sudo apt install ccal`.

Answer (score 2):

use `cal` command for default calendar. also you can install `jcal` package for jalali calendar.

[image]

Comment: +1 for your cool `$PS` that shows the current directory in reverse background color. Do you have a link for doing that?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Thanks! you can follow the instructions of this gist : https://gist.github.com/renshuki/3cf3de6e7f00fa7e744a